# composition in oop c++

Tags: c++, oop, composition

I have a problem and I hope you guys will help me solve it.
Firstly,i am Vietnamese. My English is quite bad so I have to use google to communicate with you guys.

I have 2 class: student and classActivity .
-student have some properties : name(string), mark (double), CLASS(classActivity)
-classActivity : NameClass(string),numberOfStudent(int), the list of students(student* ).

i have tried to code

```
class classActivity{};

class student {
    string name;
    int age;
    double mark;
    classActivity NameClass;
public:
    student(){}
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, student& x) {
        cin >> x.name;
        cin >> x.age;
        cin >> x.mark;
        cin >> x.NameClass;
    }
};


class classActivity {
    string nameClass;
    student* st;
    int numberOfStudent;
public:
    
    classActivity() {};
    ~classActivity() { delete[]st; }
    student& operator[] (int i) {return st[i]; }
    
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, classActivity& x) {
        
        cin >> x.nameClass;
        
        cin >> x.numberOfStudent;
        
        x.st = new student[x.numberOfStudent];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.numberOfStudent; i++) {
            cin >> x.st[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Suppose that st is instances of class student :
student st;
I realize that if I cin >> st --> it will cin >> st.NameClass --> it wil cin >> 1 all properties of class classActivity --> it will cin >> the list of students.
that action goes on repeating again and again

I hope everyone will help me solve this problem. Thank you very much for taking care of my problem

Comment: Forget about the `>>` operator, that's not the problem. The class hierarchy makes no sense. According to the shown code: `student` contains a `classActivity`, but then `classActivity` contains an array of `student`s. And each student, of course, has its own `classActivity`. Each one of those has more `student`s, and so on, infinitely. The behavior of `>>` is not a problem, it is a symptom of the real problem: broken class design. It is unclear what this class design is supposed to represent. You need to figure out your class design, first.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks you for your comment                                                                      This is just a small part of my assignment. It's a student management program
it include 4 classes: -person : name (string), age (int), address(string)
-Student inherits from class person: id(string), NameClass(classActivity),score(double)
-Lecture inherits from class person: id(string), level( like assistant professor, associate professor, full professor) 
-classActivity : NameClass(string),numberOfStudent(int), the list of students(student* ).

Comment: This program includes adding or removing students to the list. Search and sort the list of students.Using template,exception,
operator [],<<,>>,=

Comment: _This is just a small part of my assignment._ But even the design of this small part is broken. It simply cannot work this way. That you cannot find a sufficient order to define your two classes is a symptom of this. You have to create a clear hierarchy: e.g. a `classActivity` which owns all `student`s, or a `student` which owns one (or more) `classActivity`(s), or another class e.g. `project` which owns all `student`s and all `classActivity`(s) where `student`s and `classActivity`s may refer to each other without ownership.

Comment: thanks @Scheff . "a classActivity which owns all students and a student which owns one classActivity(s)" How do I fix my code to meet the this requirement

Comment: _a classActivity which owns all students and a student which owns one classActivity(s)_ I didn't wrote _and_. I wrote **_or_** and I meant _exclusive or_ (aka. either or).

Comment: At best, I can imagine that a `classActivity` might own `student`s which in turn might own a `classActivity` _but_ the `classActivity` instance owned by a `student` can never be a `classActivity` instance which owns the `student` instance. (Otherwise, you have a cyclic ownership which is a design problem in C++ as well as in real life.)

Comment: Another question: Is there any reason (e.g. restriction by teacher) to not to use `std::vector`? I would warmly recommend to not to use `new` and the C++ standard library provides really enough that you can write serious applications without any `new` or `new[]` nowadays. This can take a lot of head-ache away from you (and that was actually the intention). ;-)

Comment: You mentioned that English is not your first lang. (Not mine as well.) Hence, this might be a wording problem. I believe what you need might be: `classActivity` which owns `student`s, and `student` which refers to it's "parent" `classActivity` (but without ownership). Could this be correct?

Comment: "classActivity which owns students, and student which refers to it's "parent" classActivity (but without ownership)." 
This is what I mean. haha.Sorry for the inconvenience.
Actually, I've been studying English for 10 years. What I learned in school was vocabulary, grammar(like tenses, conditional sentences,), and reading. We rarely practice speaking, writing, or listening, so I am very bad at those abilities.

Comment: I'm just about to sketch how this could be solved. Please, [edit] your question and provide a sample input with say 1 classActivity and 3 students. I'm uncertain how this input could look like. (The `cin >> NameClass;` in `oprator>>(std::istream&, student&)` makes me uncertain.)

Comment: How this could look like: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa2ddf4f72927e7a)

Comment: I said: "You need to figure out your class design, first". I did not say "you need to show a complete and a total description of your entire homework assignment". That's not the same thing. Nobody can tell you how your classes should be designed. You need to figure it out yourself. There's nothing in your homework assignment that tells you exactly how your classes should be designed, only their mutual logical relationship. Based on their logical relationship the class design implements that logical relationship. How you do that is up to you. The current design does not work.

Comment: thanks @SamVarshavchik.Thank you for spending time with me

Comment: @Scheff Many thanks! I really appreciate it.Thank you for spending time with me